# I can't remove file, created by memmap

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I can't remove file created `numpy.memmap` funtion

```
class MyClass
 def __init__(self):    
  self.fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=flushed_chunk_shape)
    ...
 def __del__(self):   
  del self.fp
  os.remove(filename)
```

When I run `del myclass` (instanse of MyClass) I've got error `WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file`. If I use `memmap` and deleting the file in no objected oriented way everything ok. So I consider trouble in destructor. But why it happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy memmapped files are not unmapped until garbage collected, and `del self.fp` does not ensure garbage collection.  A file which is not unmapped yet cannot be deleted.

The numpy.memmap docs say "Deletion flushes memory changes to disk".  It does not say it unmaps, because it doesn't unmap.

Solution 1.  Force garbage collection

```
import gc
...
del self.fp
gc.collect()
os.remove(filename)
```

You need to make sure there are no other references to fp anywhere, or it may not be garbage collected even in this case.

Solution 2.  Force unmap

```
self.fp._mmap.close()
del self.fp
os.remove(filename)
```

Note that in the second case, if there is an access to fp after it's closed, it will probably crash the python interpreter (not throw exception, just crash)